# Internet not connected after initial WiFi connection

Tags: wireless, firefox, google-chrome, internet, chromium

When I first turn on my computer I connect to my WiFi network. I am only able to access websites I use very frequently for the first 5-10 minutes. For example, I am able to visit google.com, however, I am unable to visit any of the links to other sites. Firefox displays the "Hmm. We're having trouble finding that site." page.

It does the same on Firefox, Chrome, and Chromium.
I am currently on Kubuntu 20.04, but I also ran into this problem on Linux Mint 20, and Ubuntu 20.04.

I have no problems with a wired internet connection.

```
:~$ host 8.8.8.8

8.8.8.8.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer dns.google.

:~$ host www.ebay.com

www.ebay.com is an alias for slot9428.ebay.com.edgekey.net.
slot9428.ebay.com.edgekey.net is an alias for e9428.b.akamaiedge.net.
e9428.b.akamaiedge.net has address 104.87.5.104

:~$ ls -al /etc/resolv.conf

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Aug 28 14:11 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf

:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "resolvectl status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
search Belkin
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `host 8.8.8.8` and `host www.ebay.com` and `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: Looks like you have zero connectivity and those pages are showing as offline only (or cached). Hey-N-Enema is your man, he will come up with an answer :)